# How to find the maximum gcd for a set and an integer efficiently?

Tags: set, max, greatest-common-divisor

Given a set of integer *S*, and some questions containing an integer *w*.

For each question, compute `max{gcd(w,x)} (x in S)`.

The range for all the numbers, *n*, is also given, so `w<n,x<n (x in S)`.

I have tried simply computing all the gcds, but it is not efficient enough. I think the key is doing some pretreatment so that each question can be done in O(log n) or less.

Well, this is what I tried:

```cpp
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int gcd(int a,int b){
    return b?gcd(b,a%b):a;
}
int n,m,S[1000010],w;
int main(){
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>S[i];
    }
    cin>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        cin>>w;
        int mx=0;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            mx=max(mx,gcd(w,S[j]));
        }
        cout<<mx<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you showed what you tried, one could work on it.

Comment: You speak of _O(log n)_, but the execution time should rather depend on the number of elements in the set _S_ than on the upper value range limit _n_, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

An opportunity for optimization is to reduce the subset of S to be considered. Since `gcd(w,x)` cannot be greater than `x`, elements less than the current maximum can be skipped.
*Given a set of integer*, I use `set <int> S;`:

```
        for (auto it = S.rbegin(); it != S.rend(); ++it)
            if (*it <= mx)
                break;
            else
                mx = max(mx, gcd(w, *it));
```